# Android: Downloading a .zip file

Tags: android, download, zip

I am using the [code in the link](http://www.hassanpur.com/blog/2011/04/android-development-downloading-a-file-from-the-web/) to download a .zip file. When I try to extract it, I get the error:

> The archive is is either in unknown format or damaged.

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: resolve the unknown format or damaged archive

Comment: [Download any zip from here](http://www.colorado.edu/conflict/peace/download/) and use in your sample